# How to create a multi-level index within a for loop for which a list of names indexes each dataframe [Python]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops, arch

I want to create a multi-level row index for which level 0 is the name of the list element in the list I have named environ (see code below e.g. regime1). The second level of this row index is the parameter name (e.g. alpha[1] ). The column index is the name of the type of model fit to the data (e.g. model_1). The end goal, is to create a loop, in which I can pass a list of names associated with a data series, the label of the series becomes the first level of a row multilevel index, the second level is the parameter name, the column index is the name of the model fit to the data series.

Imports:

```
from arch import arch_model
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import arch.data.sp500
```

Below is how I want the output to look like, if I printed the results of the code loop.

```
                   model_1   model_2
Regime 1 alpha[1]  0.102150  0.099596
         beta[1]   0.885206  0.899932
         mu        0.056353  0.066129
         nu             NaN  6.607229
         omega     0.017507  0.008664
                   model_1   model_2
Regime_2 alpha[1]  0.102150  0.099596
         beta[1]   0.885206  0.899932
         mu        0.056353  0.066129
         nu             NaN  6.607229
         omega     0.017507  0.008664
```

The code below is my latest attempt to get the desired output above:

```
environ = ['regime1','regime2']
data = arch.data.sp500.load()
market = data['Adj Close']
returns = 100 * market.pct_change().dropna()
returns2 = 100 * market.pct_change().dropna()
datasets = [returns,returns2]
for i,j in zip(environ,datasets):
    model1 = arch_model(datasets[j]).fit(disp='off')
    model2 = arch_model(datasets[j], dist='t').fit(disp='off')
    comparison = pd.DataFrame( OrderedDict((('model_1',model1.params), ('model_2', model2.params))))
    print(comparison)
```

The current error I am receiving:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series
```

I don't believe fixing the error above will solve my problem. I want to return a multilevel dataframe, that looks similar to the desired output above.